# SSRS DillDown Report - Hide Columns - Visbility settings not working like I thought they should

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, visibility

I have a Tablix report with 4 groups.  The drill down is working properly, but I would like to hide certain columns either when the report is initially run or until drilldown occurs to the group.  When I try to set visibility on columns to hide then toggle on the parent group, I get an out of scope error message.  If I set hide on the columns "when the report is initially ran" it hides ALL the columns not just the columns I selected to hide.  I do not have column groups.

Here is my report design.  Please keep in mind; I'm new to SSRS and report designing.

[image: Columns. I want to hide: Speciman Code (this is a group not sure if this is causing an issue, but I've tried to group on other levels as well as trying to hide a different column instead of this one., Accession DT, Prelim SO, and FinalSO]

[image: This is the grouping]

Thanks for any help I can get!

1. I tried to Hide Column Specimen Code (which is group 1).  I set visibility to hide and to toggle on Accession_number (Parent Group).   I got an out of scope error message.
2. I selected Accession DateTime column in the Visibility settings; I selected Hide until the report is initially ran.  Results:  Hid columns, but when I went to dilldown and see the columns they were still hidden.
3. I tried to hide Accession Datetime column on the various parent groups.  I got the out of scope error message.
4. I don't have column groupings.

   I am not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column group, grouped by ="". Then you can apply the visibility to the column group.

[image]